# What is PC side development called?

Tags: .net

I've been struggling to classify what type of work I do at my job. I do .NET development for a PC side application.

Backend/Frontend seem to be mostly used for web development. Is PC side classified the same way?

Comment: "Desktop Applications Developer"?

Comment: Are you developing console apps? Graphical apps (like Win Forms or WPF?)? Or Windows Services? Games (like Unity)?

Comment: Its an add in for Microsoft Office. There are some graphical parts using WPF, but the majority is the logical side of the code.